# Subscribe/unsubscribe to an event in a list

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a list of objects and I would like to subscribe/unsubscribe each of them to an event (via a delegate because I need to pass extra params to the methods).
So I have something like this:

```
 public void MonitoringCtrl(bool monitoringOn)
    {
        foreach (var mh in monHandlers)
        {
            evHandler = (sender, e) => OnNotification(sender, e, mh);

            if (monitoringOn)
            {
                //subscribe to event
                mh.monitoredItem.Notification += evHandler;
            }
            else
            {
                //unsubscribe
                mh.monitoredItem.Notification -= evHandler;
            }
        }

        //do other stuff
    }
```

This works when subscribing, but doesn't work when unsubscribing, presumably because I re-declare the evHandler inside the foreach. How can I save the reference to the evHandler?

Comment: You could  turn your lambda into a real method. Or store your lamda as a class member.

Comment: There are already lots of Q&A on the site discussing this general scenario. You won't be able to follow the named method approach, because you rely on the captured value of `mh`. So you will have to use one of the alternatives, such as saving the delegate instance somewhere, or retrieving the `mh` value from the `sender` (e.g. if you have some mapping from `monitoredItem` back to the `mh` object that holds that reference). Actually, if you can do the latter, then a named method _will_ work.

Answer (score -1):

This is because with the second call to `MonitoringCtrl()` (when you pass `false` to unsubscribe), a new event handler is created. But that new instance does not unsubscribe an event handler instance that was attached before.

You don't need to create a new event handler for each element in the loop and you must not create new ones to unsubsribe. You could keep one single event handler for all occurances as member variable. But is even easier to do this by binding to a method like this:

```
public void MonitoringCtrl(bool monitoringOn)
{
    foreach (var mh in monHandlers)
    {
        if (monitoringOn)
        {
            //subscribe to event
            mh.monitoredItem.Notification += HandleNotification;
        }
        else
        {
            //unsubscribe
            mh.monitoredItem.Notification -= HandleNotification;
        }
    }

    //do other stuff
}

private void HandleNotification(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //do event stuff
}
```

> **Update I just saw that you need to use delegates to caputre additional arguments**

You could use local functions to capture properties of the parent method but in your case, you would need to capture the loop variable. That won't work so I'd try to find a way to get the `mh` out of the `sender` because it seems to be related. Is the `sender` the `monitoredItem` and it's parent the `monitorHandler` you want to pass with the lambda (`mh`)?